# How can I override the ENGINE=INNODB parameter while importing a MySQL dump file?

Tags: database, import, innodb, mysql

I have a big dump (tens of GB) and I would like to import it into a new table without respecting the ENGINE=INNODB parameter.

I tried several editors dedicated for large files to edit the dump but it always takes a lot of time to save the modifications, so it would make much more sense to just ignore the ENGINE=INNODB parameter and override it (for example with the default engine).

Importing and then changing the engine would not be an option as InnoDB is extremely slow to import the dump, so it would take days.

Answer (score 10):

`mysqldump --compatible=no_table_options`

worked for me

Answer (score 6):

If you are on a linux/unix system how about an in place edit with sed

```
sed -i 's/ENGINE=INNODB/ENGINE=MYISAM/g' filename
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, in the unlikely event that some of the data in the database actually contains the text `ENGINE=INNODB`, this command would corrupt the data.

Comment: use `sed -i -re 's/^(\) ENGINE=)INNODB/\1MyISAM/gi'`, it should be safe since there should be no unencoded newlines in the actual data.

Comment: Great Halped a Lot. Thanks :)